# Log4Net C# - não grava no banco de dados

Tags: c#, log4net

Estou utilizando o log4Net como framework de Log para uma WinForms APP.

```
public class Logger
{
private ILog _logErro;
private const string LogErro = "LoggerErro";

public Logger()
{
    Configure();
}

private void Configure()
{
    _logErro = LogManager.GetLogger(LogErro);
}

public void Erro(string mensagem)
{
    _logErro.Error(mensagem);
}

}
```

No assemblyinfo.cs eu acrescentei

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.Config", Watch = true)]
```

O arquivo log4net.Config tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="1" />
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_date" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@thread" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_level" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@logger" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@message" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>

<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>

</appender>
<root>
<level value="All" />
<appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />   
</root>
</log4net>
```

Quando executo o comando:

`Logger.Erro("Mensagem de erro");`

Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas também não grava no banco de dados.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar protected na declaração da variável ao invés de private? Eu aqui utilizo log4net, porém faço apresentação de debugs e erros de mensagens jogando desta maneira: `protected static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`

Comment: Daniel, eu estava usando o SQL EXPRESS para gravar os logo aí não funcionava, quando alterei para o SQL SERVER funcionou. Vou testar sua sugestão.